# Unique value in either one of two columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a very simple table which contains a couple of columns:

```
ID           (int)
Sender ID    (int)
Recipient ID (int)
Date Time    (DateTime)
MessageText  (varchar(255))
```

The thing is, I would like to retrieve the latest record from this table where the Sender ID OR the Recipient ID equals my user ID, BUT I also want the other column to be unique.

Let me give you an example, I have some rows with the following data:

```
    ID    Sender   Recipient          Date              Message
    1       1         2       2011-01-01 01:55:00    Test Data
    2       1         2       2011-01-01 01:56:00    Test Data 2
    3       2         1       2011-01-01 01:59:00    Some more test data
    4       3         1       2011-01-02 11:50:00    Test Data 3
```

I would like my query/stored procedure to return 2 rows on this data. The rows with ID 3 and the one with ID 4, but I can't seem to figure this out in a single stored procedure.

**EDIT: Found it, if anyone has any optimizations, please let me know**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetRootMessages
    @UserID         int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OtherUserID int

    CREATE TABLE #TempMessages 
    (
        ID int, 
        SenderID int, 
        RecipientID int, 
        MessageText text, 
        SendDate datetime not null, 
        ReadDate datetime null, 
        ReplyTo int null);

    DECLARE idCursor    Cursor FOR
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT SenderID as OtherUserID FROM Messages WHERE RecipientID = @UserID
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT RecipientID as OtherUserID FROM Messages WHERE SenderID = @UserID
    );

    OPEN idCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM idCursor INTO @OtherUserID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TempMessages (ID, SenderID, RecipientID, MessageText, SendDate, ReadDate, ReplyTo)
        SELECT TOP 1 * 
        FROM Messages 
        WHERE (SenderID = @UserID AND RecipientID = @OtherUserID) OR (SenderID = @OtherUserID AND RecipientID = @UserID)
        ORDER BY SendDate DESC

        FETCH NEXT FROM idCursor INTO @OtherUserID
    END
    CLOSE idCursor
    DEALLOCATE idCursor

    SELECT * FROM #TempMessages ORDER BY SendDate DESC
    DROP TABLE #TempMessages
END
```

Comment: can you tell what is the physical sense? what functionality do you  want to achieve?

Comment: I want to show a list of messages, but only the last message send or received per user.  So essentially it is a list of users which send the user (or received a message from the user) and the latest message send/received.

Comment: why don't you just add `order by id desc limit 2` to your query?

Comment: It's pretty complicated to explain. I want it to return a list like the SMS application on the iPhone. I want to show the user a list of users that was messaged by or send the user a message. Only showing the last message that was received or send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005+:

```
WITH ordered AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    Person1 = CASE WHEN Sender > Recipient THEN Recipient ELSE Sender END,
    Person2 = CASE WHEN Sender > Recipient THEN Sender ELSE Recipient END
  FROM atable
),
ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person1, Person2 ORDER BY Date DESC)
  FROM ordered
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Sender,
  Recipient,
  Date,
  Message
FROM ranked
WHERE rank = 1
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I will try to see if this gives the right results. Its a lot cleaner than using cursors and temporay tables.

Comment: Yup, it works. I did add a where clause to only get messages with a certain Sender or Recipient.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
;WITH tab (row, ID, Sender, Recipient, Date, Message)
AS (select row_number() over (order by date desc), * 
  from table
 where ([Sender ID] = @id or [Recipient ID] = @id)
   and ID <> [Sender ID]
   and ID <> [Recipient ID]
   and [Sender ID] <> [Recipient ID])
SELECT ID, Sender, Recipient, Date, Message
  FROM tab 
 WHERE row = 1
```

Basically, you get a list of all the records for your user id and give them a number ordered by date. The first can then be picked up as the most recent one.

Below the complete script I used to reproduce.
    create table mails(
    ID           int,
    Sender    int,
    Recipient int,
    [Date]    DateTime,
    MessageText  varchar(255))

```
insert into mails values
    (1 ,      1  ,       2 ,      '2011-01-01 01:55:00' ,   'Test Data'),
    (2 ,      1  ,       2 ,      '2011-01-01 01:56:00' ,   'Test Data 2'),
    (3 ,      2  ,       1 ,      '2011-01-01 01:59:00' ,   'Some more test data'),
    (4 ,      3   ,      1 ,      '2011-01-02 11:50:00' ,   'Test Data 3')

    declare @id int
    select @id = 1

;WITH tab (row, ID, Sender, Recipient, [Date], Message)
AS (select row_number() over (order by [Date] desc), * 
  from mails
 where ([Sender] = @id or [Recipient] = @id)
   and ID <> [Sender]
   and ID <> [Recipient]
   and [Sender] <> [Recipient])
SELECT ID, Sender, Recipient, [Date], Message
  FROM tab 
 WHERE row = 1
```

To get a list of messages sorted by newest first you can use this query:

```
select * 
  from mails
 where ([Sender] = @id or [Recipient] = @id)
   and ID <> [Sender]
   and ID <> [Recipient]
   and [Sender] <> [Recipient]
 order by [Date] desc
```

Comment: I think I will try this. Thanks, it seems like this is something I could use.

Comment: This brought me almost to what I wanted, except the @row variable is always NULL. Somehow it doesn't get a value assigned (it should get the value from the row_number() I guess?

Comment: The `@row` was a typo, it should have been `row`

Comment: Hmm, this only returns the last message received, but what I would like to do is show per user what the last message was. Like in the iPhone SMS app, it shows a list of messages, which all are the last message to/from a user.

Comment: I interpreted "I would like to retrieve the latest record" as the last message. I will update the answer to also show how to get the list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am not missing something couldn't you do this? Where X is the ID you want to find?

```
select * 
 from TABLE
where (SENDER=x and RECIPIENT<>x) 
   OR (SENDER<>x and RECIPIENT=x);
```

or to get just latest ones

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE SENDER=X 
   AND RECIPIENT <> X
   AND DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE) 
                 FROM TABLE 
                WHERE SENDER=X)
UNION
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE SENDER <> X 
   AND RECIPIENT = X 
   AND DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE) 
                 FROM TABLE 
                WHERE RECIPIENT=X)
```

Comment: I see you need to get the latest one, so my original answer isn't complete. I provided a second set of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1:

```
SELECT Sender, Recipient
FROM Messages
GROUP BY Sender, Recipient
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

This will get you a list of unique sender and recipient pairs, but you would need to use this as a subquery or as part of a join to get the list of unique messages.

Version 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM Messages O
WHERE NOT EXIST
(SELECT *
 FROM Messages I
 WHERE I.ID <> O.ID AND I.Sender = O.Sender AND I.Recipient = O.Recipient)
```

It's also possible to write this as a left outer join, but I don't want to try.

Answer (score 0):

I think ammianus is on the right track.

Basically you want to use DISTINCT to get only the unique ones, and UNION to combine the two queries which you'll get.

Comment: I don't think so, because then I will end up with 2 rows PER user and I only want to have 1 row per user.

Answer (score 0):

Try thisone:

```
declare @UserID int
select @UserID = 1

-- Union all messages in one table and filter them on our userid
declare @Union table(ID int, UserID int, SendDate datetime, Message nvarchar(50))
insert into @Union(ID, UserID, SendDate, Message)
select ID, RecipientID, SendDate, Message
from Messages
where SenderID = @UserID
union
select ID, SenderID, SendDate, Message
from Messages
where RecipientID = @UserID

    -- Gets max dates for every correspond user
declare @MaxDates table(UserID int, SendDate datetime)
insert into @MaxDates(UserID, SendDate)
select UserID, max(SendDate)
from @Union
group by UserID

    -- Gets result
select u.*
from @Union u
    inner join @MaxDates md on (u.UserID = md.UserID) and (u.SendDate = md.SendDate)
```